# how to store result of sys.stdout.write in a global variable in Python

Tags: python, stdout

How can I use the result of sys.stdout.write(output) as a global variable.
Following is the part of the code.
output of sys.stdout.write is words and it keeps appending till 140 characters are completed.

```
for i in range(140):
    x = numpy.reshape(pattern, (1, len(pattern), 1))
    x = x / float(num_vocab)
    pred = model.predict(x, verbose=0)
    index = numpy.argmax(pred)
    output = int_to_char[index]
    #print('Output',output)
    OutputTweet.append(output)
    seq_in = [int_to_char[value] for value in pattern]
    sys.stdout.write(output)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    pattern.append(index)
    pattern = pattern[1:len(pattern)]
```

Comment: What did you expect? I think the result of sys.stdout.write(output) is just the `output` variable, or `''.join(OutputTweet)` represents.

Answer (score 1):

The *result* of `sys.stdout.write` isn't very useful—it's just the number of characters in whatever you wrote. Of course you can store that in a global variable:

```
written = 0

def myfunc():
    global written
    written += sys.stdout.write(blahblah)
```

… but I can't see why you'd *want* to.

---

What `sys.stdout.write` writes to the terminal (or redirected file, or whatever) seems a lot more useful. But you already *have* that. You're doing this:

```
sys.stdout.write(output)
```

So, what it writes is going to be exactly what's in `output`. So just store that. For example:

```
outputs = []
def myfunc():
    global outputs
    output = blah blah blah
    sys.stdout.write(output)
    outputs.append(output)
```

---

Now, if you have no control over the function that's writing stuff, because it's in some library that you're not allowed to modify or something, you *can* capture its output. This is usually not a good idea, but if you need to, you can write a wrapper around the real `sys.stdout` that saves the output and then passes it through to the real thing (or doesn't, if you don't want it to hit the screen), and then just assign `sys.stdout = mywrapper`. But if you can't figure out how to write that, you almost certainly don't want to.